# Boost Log File Rotation not working as expected

Tags: c++, boost

I do not have much experience with using boost library. I am using boost library to maintain system logs with file rotation but it is not working as expected.
Log files are being created **endlessly**.
When the file size is reached i.e. 1 MB, a new log file is created. At the moment I want only 5 log files to exist having a size of 1 MB each and new logs must be appended in place of the older logs. The memory allocated for log files must not exceed 5 MB at any instance. Kindly help. I am using the following function to initialize log rotation.

```
static void fnInitSystemLogging(string logfile, bool log_level)
{
    static const std::string COMMON_FMT("[%TimeStamp%] [%Severity%]:\t%Message%");

    boost::log::register_simple_formatter_factory< boost::log::trivial::severity_level, char >("Severity");

    // get current data and time and convert it into string
    boost::posix_time::ptime timeLocal = boost::posix_time::second_clock::local_time();
    const std::string str_date = to_simple_string(timeLocal.date());
    const std::string str_time = to_simple_string(timeLocal.time_of_day());

    // Output message to console
    boost::log::add_console_log(
        std::cout,
        boost::log::keywords::format = COMMON_FMT,
        boost::log::keywords::auto_flush = true
    );

    // Output message to file, rotates when file reached 1mb or at midnight every day. Each log file
    // is capped at 1mb and total is 5mb
    boost::log::add_file_log (
        boost::log::keywords::file_name = logfile + "_" +  str_date + "_" + str_time + "_%3N.log",
        boost::log::keywords::rotation_size = 1 * 1024 * 1024,
        boost::log::keywords::max_size = 5 * 1024 * 1024,
        boost::log::keywords::max_files = 5,
        boost::log::keywords::time_based_rotation = boost::log::sinks::file::rotation_at_time_point(0, 0, 0),
        boost::log::keywords::format = COMMON_FMT,
        boost::log::keywords::auto_flush = true
    );

    boost::log::add_common_attributes();

    // Only output message with INFO or higher severity in Release
// #ifndef _DEBUG
    if(log_level)
        boost::log::core::get()->set_filter(boost::log::trivial::severity >= boost::log::trivial::info);
    else
        boost::log::core::get()->set_filter(boost::log::trivial::severity >= boost::log::trivial::error);

//#endif
}
```

Comment: Please tell us what you expect and what you currently have. What do you mean by "created endlessly"?

Comment: Expected behavior: To generate 5 log files (test1.log, test2.log, ... , test5.log) in total each having a size of 1 MB. When log size exceeds 5 MB instead of creating a new log file (test6.log), the system should remove old logs and add logs to the existing log file (eg. test5.log assuming the latest logs are always appended in test1.log)

Current Behavior:  When log size exceeds 5 MB a new log file (test6.log) is created. and when 1 MB size is reached a new log file is created hence creating log files endlessly.

Comment: @Hizza could you edit your question to make that clearer? Right now the comment is hard to read and it looks like it duplicates the majority of the question. Perhaps drop it into the question and format it a bit

Answer (score 3):

Maintaining the limits on the total size and number of files is a functionality of a [file collector](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/detailed/sink_backends.html#log.detailed.sink_backends.text_file.file_collection). A file collector is created for a target storage directory, to which the rotated files are moved on rotation. You must specify the target storage directory in the `keywords::target` argument to enable file collector and all associated limits. The target storage directory can be the same as where the currently written log file is located.

Comment: +1 I think I've seen the question asked dozens of times now, and this is the first time I've seen a targeted answer that I can remember. Is there a way we can improve the docs to prevent this recurring surprise?

Comment: Thankyou Andrey for your help, including the target keyword solved my problem. Specifying the target directory enabled file rotation.

Comment: @sehe I've added a note to the `add_file_log` description, although it seemed rather clear to me that in order to maintain target directory limits one has to specify it first.

Comment: Thanks @AndreySemashev - Sometimes empirical evidence is the best guide. I agree that - iff I'm going from [this page](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/log/doc/html/boost/log/add_file_log.html) it was already pretty clear. My guess is many people come from samples instead.  I'd love for the keywords to be grouped (like `collector::max_size`) but since that's already gone I suppose we can help steer people with a few redundant hints left and right.

Answer (score 0):

You should precise `boost::log::keywords::max_files`.

```c++
    boost::log::add_file_log (
        boost::log::keywords::file_name = logfile + "_" +  str_date + "_" + str_time + "_%3N.log",
        boost::log::keywords::rotation_size = 1 * 1024 * 1024,
        boost::log::keywords::max_size = 5 * 1024 * 1024,
        boost::log::keywords::time_based_rotation = boost::log::sinks::file::rotation_at_time_point(0, 0, 0),
        boost::log::keywords::format = COMMON_FMT,
        boost::log::keywords::auto_flush = true,
        boost::log::keywords::max_files = 5
    );
```

Comment: Adding the keyword "max_files" has no effect. Experiencing the same behavior.

Comment: Are you sure you recompiled? Do you have multiple instances of this program running in parallel? Multiple threads running this code?

Comment: Also note that these log rotation constraints only apply to the current instance running. Every time you run your program, it will start from scratch by creating a new file and respecting all these constraints.

Comment: Yes I did recompile the code. Also I am aware of the constraint that every run will create it's own files.

Comment: The same instance creates more than 5 files with these constraints?

Comment: Yes it does unfortunately.